# How to tweak the Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I recently upgraded from EF Core 2.2.6 to 3.1 and I am facing lots of performance degradation issues.

I have the below query could someone help me with how i can optimize this query so that the values are loaded much faster.

```
var valuations = await _context.Valuation
                               .Where(a => a.PortfolioCompany.DealCode == dealCode && 
                                           a.ValuationPeriod.PeriodName == periodName)
                               .Include(a => a.ValuationPeriod)
                               .Include(x => x.ValuationState)
                               .Include(x => x.PortfolioCompany)
                               .ThenInclude(up => up.UserPermission)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

_context.Entry(valuations).Collection(a => a.ValuationFundTemplate).Load();
_context.Entry(valuations)
        .Collection(a => a.UserValuationAssignments).Query()
        .Include(u => u.User).Load();

return valuations;
```

When there are lots of includes, the performance drops. Please help me with this.

The includes that you see here are not collections:

```
public virtual ValuationPeriod ValuationPeriod { get; set; }
```

Comment: Were the performance issues just introduced when you upgraded from 2.2.6 to 3.1?  (Ran faster in 2.2.6)  Run a profiler in 2.2.6 vs. 3.1 and capture the SQL query(ies) being generated by both. This would likely highlight any difference in behaviour. From what I can see of what you post, why `Load` the Template and User separate instead of using `Include` for them as well?

Comment: @StevePy i have tried that and i see a major difference when using 2.2.6 and 3.1.
When it is not collection how do i seperate the query?

Comment: For the community to help you faster we need a bit more information: like what SQL is being generated by different versions? What is the schema? What are you trying to select? What indexes are defined?

Answer (score 0):

The Fund Template(s) and User Valuation Assignments should be able to be Included within the query rather than loaded afterwards. If these valuations are being returned, where/what are they being returned to? Is this an MVC controller method returning these entities to a view? or a service returning this entity graph so that details can be queried and/or updated?

```
var valuations = await _context.Valuation
                           .Where(a => a.PortfolioCompany.DealCode == dealCode && 
                                       a.ValuationPeriod.PeriodName == periodName)
                           .Include(a => a.ValuationPeriod)
                           .Include(x => x.ValuationState)
                           .Include(x => x.PortfolioCompany)
                           .ThenInclude(up => up.UserPermission)
                           .Include(x => x.ValuationFundTemplate)
                           .Include(x => x.UserValuationAssignments)
                           .ThenInclude(a => a.User)
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Run the above statement or your original ones if the above is missing something using EF Core 2.2.6 and Core 3.1 with a Profiler running against your database. For SQL Server for instance the SSMS (management studio) has a built in profiler, or you can use a lightweight one like Express Profiler. It helps to run against an isolated database instance such as a local database or a test replica that only your test instance is running against so you don't have to sift through the noise of other queries running from test environments or other devs. Set a breakpoint then let the query run. Capture the SQL and execution time, then let the code complete. Was this the only query run, or for instance when the calling method completes were there additional queries being executed? (I.e. extra lazy load calls)

Compare the SQL and performance between 2.2.6 and 3.1 to look for clues as to what happened. I've recently seen cases where Core 2.2.6 will compile queries quite differently to Core 3.1 so this could be a breaking change or bug in 3.1. (The only certainty when developing on the bleeding edge is that you're going to get bloody. :)

If this is a controller method or the like returning data to a view, consider using `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` to load data from the entity graph into a view model structure suited to the view. This negates the need to use `Include` to eager load, or hit performance issues with lazy load calls tripped by serialization. It also generates more efficient queries and cuts down on the amount of data transmitted over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a check which sql is slow. (as you described it's the first one?)

EF3 does have a change might cause the issue:

> Caution
>
> Since version 3.0.0, each Include will cause an additional JOIN to be added to SQL queries produced by relational providers, whereas previous versions generated additional SQL queries. This can significantly change the performance of your queries, for better or worse. In particular, LINQ queries with an exceedingly high number of Include operators may need to be broken down into multiple separate LINQ queries in order to avoid the cartesian explosion problem.

Normally I prefer to select only the necessary data by using `Select` to put the result into a dto, other than the db entities.

Another point may be to check the generated sql execution plan to see what's the bottle neck.